# Cordova emulate/test on different mobiles/versions

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed an Cordova Android App. After I have installed it on different devices (Galaxy S6, S4, S4mini, S3mini). On the S6 and the S4 everything is working right but on the other, older models, some function are not working. What is the best way to fix it. (I dont want to change a little thing, than build it, install on my device(takes to much time) and than dont see any difference.) What is the most efficient way to find those faults, which are just on old (or some) devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the `built-in version of Weinre in Google Chrome`. Which is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging).

When you connect your mobile device to your PC and enable USB debugging on the mobile device; it will show up using the `chrome://inspect/#devices` location in your browser (use it as a url).

After starting your application on the mobile device, it will show up as a webpage. You can then debug your webapp making changes on the fly as you would when debugging a regular website.

It is also an option to set up your own Weinre server, which removes the need to connect the device to your PC. You can then add a script tag to your webapp, making the webapp show up in your Weinre client. More info can be found [here](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/Home.html).

Comment: Ok thats a good idea but can i use it as an App or did it have to be an website?

Comment: What do you mean use it as an app? You still have to build your application, but it removes the need to rebuild every time you change something. You can see the changes you make instantly as it 'behaves' as a website, but is still your application.

Comment: I mean if I can use it as an APK app or did I have to use an html file?

Comment: Yes, still use it as an APK.

Comment: Ok thanks, but it have to be Android  4.4 or above right?

Comment: Correct. You could also take a look at using `cordova serve` and making that accessible via browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the app from UI perspective in different devices, then you can add browser platform to your project and build the browser platform.

Then you can access your app using browser platform in chrome browser where you can view the app in different devices available in device mode of chrome.